# Lambda Expressions and Entity Framework, how to get the reference to an object created in another method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

SO, I have the following initializer of my ef model.

To simplify, I have One Vehicle, One Customer, One Address entities.
I created the Address entities in one method.
Now I need to create the Customer entities, but how can I assign the Address value to an existing object?

```
public class DevelopmentInitializer
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// This class allows the database tables to be created and seed at runtime.
        /// </summary>
        public class AskAndTrackInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<AskAndTrackContext>
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// This fills the database with sample data to start with
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="context">DBContext required for the connection</param>
            protected override void Seed(AskAndTrackContext context)
            {
                BuildDealers(context);
                BuildRequesters(context);
                BuildAddresses(context);
                BuildCustomers(context);
                BuildVehicles(context);

                BuildWorkflowsBase(context);
            }

            private void BuildDealers(AskAndTrackContext context)
            {
                var dealer1 = new Dealer {DealerId = 1, Name = "Dealer 1"};
                var dealer2 = new Dealer { DealerId = 2, Name = "Dealer 2" };
                var dealer3 = new Dealer { DealerId = 3, Name = "Dealer 3" };
                var dealer4 = new Dealer { DealerId = 4, Name = "Dealer 4" };
                var dealer5 = new Dealer { DealerId = 5, Name = "Dealer 5" };

                context.Dealers.Add(dealer1);
                context.Dealers.Add(dealer2);
                context.Dealers.Add(dealer3);
                context.Dealers.Add(dealer4);
                context.Dealers.Add(dealer5);

            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Requesters test data
            /// </summary>
            private void BuildRequesters(AskAndTrackContext context)
            {
                var requester1 = new Requester {EmailAddress = "le.xx@hotmail.com", Name="Andres x", RequesterId=1};
                var requester2 = new Requester { EmailAddress = "le.xxx@hotmail.com", Name = "Andres y", RequesterId = 2 };
                var requester3 = new Requester { EmailAddress = "le.yyy@hotmail.com", Name = "Juan l", RequesterId = 3 };
                var requester4 = new Requester { EmailAddress = "le.zzzz@hotmail.com", Name = "Peter x", RequesterId = 4 };
                var requester5 = new Requester { EmailAddress = "le.aaaa@hotmail.com", Name = "Patrick z", RequesterId = 5 };

                context.Requesters.Add(requester1);
                context.Requesters.Add(requester2);
                context.Requesters.Add(requester3);
                context.Requesters.Add(requester4);
                context.Requesters.Add(requester5);

            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Workflow base test data and its related objects
            /// </summary>
            private void BuildWorkflowsBase(AskAndTrackContext context)
            {

            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Vehicle test data
            /// </summary>
            private void BuildVehicles(AskAndTrackContext context)
            {
                //var vehicle1
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Customers test data
            /// </summary>
            private void BuildCustomers(AskAndTrackContext context)
            {
                //var customer1 = new Customer{Address = ???


            }

            private void BuildAddresses(AskAndTrackContext context)
            {
                var address1 = new Address
                                    {
                                        AddressId = 1,
                                        Box = "71",
                                        City = "Antwerp",
                                        Number = "1",
                                        Street = "Belgielei",
                                        Zip = "2018"
                                    };

                var address2 = new Address
                                    {
                                        AddressId = 2,
                                        Box = "21",
                                        City = "Antwerp",
                                        Number = "1",
                                        Street = "Lange Leemstraat",
                                        Zip = "2018"
                                    };

                var address3 = new Address
                                    {
                                        AddressId = 3,
                                        Box = "23",
                                        City = "Antwerp",
                                        Number = "1",
                                        Street = "Lamoriniestraat",
                                        Zip = "2018"
                                    };

                var address4 = new Address
                                    {
                                        AddressId = 4,
                                        Box = "24",
                                        City = "Antwerp",
                                        Number = "1",
                                        Street = "De Keyserlei",
                                        Zip = "2000"
                                    };

                var address5 = new Address
                                    {
                                        AddressId = 5,
                                        Box = "34",
                                        City = "Antwerp",
                                        Number = "1",
                                        Street = "Italialei",
                                        Zip = "2020"
                                    };

                context.Addresses.Add(address1);
                context.Addresses.Add(address2);
                context.Addresses.Add(address3);
                context.Addresses.Add(address4);
                context.Addresses.Add(address5);

            }
        }
```

Comment: lol I think this has nothing to do with lambda expressions, or does it?

Comment: are you using EF code first, or an EDM Model? Please, so the classes or the EDM model depending on your option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In EF Code First you must declare the relation between two entities declaring a list of the children entities in the partent entity

```
public List<ChildeEntity> ChildEntities { get; set; }
```

Then, if you create a ChildEntity:

```
var newChild = new ChildEntity();
```

and you add it to the list of a parent entity:

```
parentEntity.ChildEntities.Add(newChild);
```

If the parent entity is in the context, the newChild will be put automatically in context, and, when you wave changes, the necessary properties of the child (FK properties) will be set in newChild before saving the changed to the database.

So, the answer, is: simply add it to the parent's list.

In fact, the relation is expressed in 3 ways:

- the parent's list of children entities
- a property in the child entity that points to the parent
- a FK (which can be included in the entity or not)

If you're working in context, whenever you change any of the 3 properties, the others are corrected in the context accordingly.

So the answer can include changing any of the other properties.

Answer (score 0):

I see two options: (that don't have nothing to do with lambda expressions ;)

1. You can call `BuildCustomers` from inside `BuildAdresses`;

   ```
   private void BuildAddresses(AskAndTrackContext context)
   {
       var listAddress = new List<Address>();
       // create adresses, populate listAdress with the Address objects. 
       BuildCustomers(AskAndTrackContext context, listAddress);
   }
   ```
2. `BuildAdresses` can return a list of IDs, and you pass the list as a parameter to `BuildCustomers`.

   ```
   List<Address> addresses = BuildAddresses(context);
   BuildCustomers(context, addresses);
   ```

Don't forget to call `context.SaveChanges()` in the end of each populating function. This way Entity will know the object you are passing is an element from a table.

Both solutions will do the same thing, but the readability will be different.

Comment: yes, but how can I assign the reference to the object address inside the object customer instantiation?

Comment: see the quoation marks ?? on my code to understand the question pls.

Comment: Ah, alright: first I see you need to use `context.SaveChanges()` after the series of `Add` command. This way you will add the items to the database and if you reference the object, Entity will understand it is an element from a database. See my edit!